# Oracle optimizer using functions in sql statements

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, query-optimization

I have an external API developed in PL/SQL (Oracle 11.2g) that I use with my module SQL statements. This is a extremely simplified example:

```
select *
from (select column_value c from table(api_pkg.function(param1, param2))) t1
join table2 t2
  on t2.pkc = t1.c
...
```

Where table2.pkc is the PK for such table. The problem is that the query performance is very low as the optimizer does not use table2 index.

If I create a table

```
create table tmp_result as 
select column_value c from table(api_pkg.function(param1, param2))
```

And I use it in the first query, the optimizer uses table2 index

```
select *
from tmp_result t1
join table2 t2
  on t2.pkc = t1.c
```

And the performance is great. It is reasonable to think that since Oracle doesn't know the number of rows that will be returned by the function, it cannot optimize the query properly.

The original query joins 23 tables and I have few other ones using this approach with good execution plans, so I'm not willing to add hints to force the correct execution plan. Instead, can I force the optimizer to find out first the amount of rows returned by the function and then generate the plan? Or of course, any other approach?

So far I tried http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_materialize_sql_hint.htm with no success nor I was able to force using the specific index with hints.

Comment: How many rows is your function likely to usually return? Is it likely to be wildly differing (ie. 1 row vs 1 million rows, depending on the parameters), or roughly similar? If the latter, then you could look into using the cardinality hint to say how many rows are expected. It doesn't have to be entirely accurate - e.g  if you were returning 3000 rows, 1000 is likely to be a good enough "guess", but if you're expecting 1 million rows and you actually get 10, then you might not get the best plan.

Comment: @Daniel Gutierrez - Did you try using an index hint in the query? Something like `/*+ index(t2 t2_idex_name) */` ... That should go just after the `SELECT` key word.

Comment: You might have a look at `ASSOCIATE STATISTICS` for applying extended statistics to functions http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=426

Comment: @Boneist, the rows returned are limited to a range from 1 to 5000, so I tried the cardinality hint and it did impact the execution plan as expected. The execution plan is still different than if I use the temp table but I stil consider your answer as correct solution. Since you posted it as a comment I cannot flag it as correct answer.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, after applying the hint, the execution plan becomes more similar to the one when I use the temp table and the total cost is in fact lower. Unfortunately, the more costly plan with temp table is still 10x faster than the less costly plan using api+hint, so at this point I dont think that better stats will help.

Comment: Actually this article on the same site is probably better suited to your scenario: [setting cardinality for pipelined and table functions](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=427)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, I tried dynamic_sampling and improves the cost for the function, so from this point of view this hint is more correct (it is documented) than cardinality one. In any case, the result is the same: cost for "collection iterator" reflects the precise cardinality for the api call but the whole execution plan is slightly different (better cost) and the execution much slower. Maybe the reason is that the "collection iterator" cost is slightly higher than the "full scan" of the tmp table and this small change causes a dramatic change in the execution plan and overall performance.

Comment: Yes the cost will change with dynamic sampling. So what? I never look at it.

Comment: What I meant is that the execution plan when using the function is still a bit different so I had to remove its usage. In any case, the valid answer for the original question is using dynamic_sampling as suggested in the link you provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try moving this subquery to `with` clause. It may help.

If you don't want hints like `ORDERED` or `INDEX` it may be hard to force optimiser to count it unless you insert results to temporary table first.